# Excision property for non measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

I'm studying measure theory from the book *Real Analysis* by H. Royden & P. Fitzpatrick. I'm stuck at the question 19 of the chapter 2.

The question is:

> Let $E$ has finite outer measure. If $E$ is not measurable, then there is an open set $O$ containing $E$ that has finite measure and for which $m^*(O\setminus E) > m^*(O) - m^*(E)$

Applying the definition of measurability, i get a set satisfying the inequality but cannot find an open set.

PS: I've found [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444517/excision-property-false-when-set-is-not-measurable) but it has no answers. So i decided to ask again.

Comment: Try regularity of Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @bof just fixed my mistake. It should be outer measure.

Comment: @Jakobian i have tried but it gives me only an $\epsilon $ with $m^*(O\setminus E) > \epsilon $ for all open sets $O$ containing $E$. How can i continue to get RHS of the inequality?

Comment: It boils down to showing that Catheodory criterion of measurability doesn't hold for every such open set $O$.